# Displaying web service response as HTML on VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, http

I need to get html code from a web service and display it in a VF page. I've tried the following, but it's showing the response as text, not as html.

**VF**

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" controller="GetBlueDotMenu">
    <apex:outputText value="{!response}" />
</apex:page>
```

**APEX**

```
public with sharing class GetBlueDotMenu {
    public String response {get; set;}
    public GetBlueDotMenu() {
        QbApiController api = new QbApiController ('GET', 'QB API' , null, null, 'https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/Account/AppMenu');
        response = api.execute();
    }
}
```

api.execute() returns the response body.

I've tried messing with the HttpResponse class, but can't figure out how to send the response to the visualforce page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `apex:outputText` tag escapes content by default.  If you'd like to display HTML content you'll want to set the escape attribute to false.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" controller="GetBlueDotMenu">
    <apex:outputText value="{!response}" escape="false"/>
</apex:page>
```